# $A$ is finitely generated free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finitely-generated, free-modules

$R$ is left noetherian. $A$ is finitely generated $R$-module. Then $A$ is finitely generated free.

I can't see why it is free. I know that $A$ is finitely presented, so there is an exact sequence:

$0 \to P \to F\to A \to 0$ where $F$ is free and both $F, P $ are finitely generated. But a quotient of free module is not necessarily free, right? So how is $A$ free? Any help would be apprecited!

Comment: No way! $A$ is not necessarily free. You probably missed an extra condition.

Comment: Thx very much for the confirmation! I am not sure... This is from Rotman's Introduction to homological algebra. In theorem 10.66 it is stated as such and then it says the hypothesis of Lemma 3.55 is satisfied. The hypothesis there is for finitely generated free, not finitely presented. So I thought f.p. might imply f. g. free?

Comment: $R=\mathbb{Z}, A=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a counterexample.